# return ng-template from service angular4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I created a service which returns the html and i use it with [innerHtml]. Now i want to return the ng-template along with html. Can you please guide me how it can be done.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: I tired to use https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml and it start rendring but changed ngbPopover  to ngbpopover Due to this Tooltip is not working

Comment: @micronyks i changed the question , can you please share some thoughts now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just "return `ng-template`" - to turn HTML fragment into `ng-template` (I guess it is `TemplateRef` that you are after...) you would have to *compile* given HTML fragment. This is really *not* something you want to do as loading compiler into a browser and the actual compilation is relatively slow.

tl;dr; is that you can't simply add Angular directives into an HTML fragment, do `innerHTML` and expect things to work. This is not how Angular operates.

It seems to me like you are trying to use Angular-based directive (`ngbPopover`) in the non-Angular context (some jQuery plugin?) but this is *not* how things work in the current Angular. You need to use angular directives in Angular context.